# C++11 List/Set/Vector Atomic Get and pop

Tags: c++, mutex, atomic

What I want to achieve: Having a set of unordered numbers, I would like to atomically select a random (or first, or whatever) element **and** remove from the set in the same operation.

Currently, I have:

```cpp
std::list<int> pool = {1, 2, 3, ...};
int handle = pool.front();
pool.pop_front();
```

However, this does not ensure atomicity! I had hoped something like this existed:

```
std::list<int> pool = {1, 2, 3, ...};
int handle = pool.pop_front();
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You have to do that on your own using an appropriate synchronization mechanism like a `std::mutex` or alike.

Comment: Such operation can't be atomic, at least lock-free. If you are looking for lock-free library - check [libcds](https://github.com/khizmax/libcds)